# How to Extract Strings from a text file and copy them to excel sheet using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have plenty of text files containing data like this:

```
refresh: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.Refresh) %>',
close: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.Close) %>',
all: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.All) %>',
entries: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("DepMethodEdit_Entries") %>',
archive: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("worklist_Archive") %>',
onequarter: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("worklist_onequarter") %>',
halfyear: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("worklist_halfyear") %>',
oneyear: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("worklist_oneyear") %>',
twoyears: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("worklist_twoyears") %>',
customize: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("CBW_EditDashlet") %>',
notSentLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("status-notsend") %>',
sentLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("status-sent") %>',
errorSendingLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("status-error") %>',
openLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.Open) %>',
rejectedLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("DocumentStatus_Rejected") %>',
normalLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("Normal") %>',
creditLabel: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.Credit) %>',
deleteinvoice: '<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("ProcessedInvoicingDelete") %>'
```

Is it possible to extract this string <%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText("ProcessedInvoicingDelete") %> and copy it to an excel sheet using Powershell?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You will need [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
High level:

- Get contents of the text file
- use `Select-String` or `[regex]::Matches` for each element(row)
- Export to CSV (if you don't want headers, use `Set-Content` otherwise use `Export-CSV`)
- Create an Excel ComObject
- Open a workbook, and a worksheet
- use `SaveAs` method
- quit Excel ComObject

Comment: if its just a few rows, it can also be done via Regexr or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/D7ZFBx/1) and just get result from the `Match Information` then choose `Plain Text` then copy and paste to your excel workbook