# How do I take the first word from each line in txt file and put them into an Excel sheet using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, text

I'm trying to use PowerShell to take the first word in each line of a .ctl file and put that word into an Excel sheet.

I looked at this question [How to Extract Strings from a text file and copy them to excel sheet using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578728/how-to-extract-strings-from-a-text-file-and-copy-them-to-excel-sheet-using-power) and it seems like it's what I need to do except that each word is unrelated to the others and I have no real knowledge of code. I've just been doing this manually, but there are hundreds of files.

I found this, but I'm not sure what function would select the first word

```
$lines = Get-Content "C:\ExampleFolder\Example.txt"

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    Write-Host ($line.Split(" "))[0]
}
```

An example line looks like this:

```
branch_description NULLIF branch_description='    8]^NULL^[' "substr(:branch_description,6)",
```

I would just need the "branch_description" portion, the rest can be ignored.

This is going to be performed on hundreds of files in a folder. How would I loop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete code does it:

```
$lines = Get-Content "C:\ExampleFolder\Example.txt"
```

Reads the File and stores an array of strings. every line in the file is one element of the array

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
```

This part of the code is the beginning of a loop. It loops through the array of strings and does the following code in the brackets to every element in the array

```
  Write-Host ($line.Split(" "))[0]
```

Here comes the magic. Write-Host is just for the output on your powershell-window. You have to replace this command to something, that writes into your excel- or csv-file (or to store it in a array for later use)

The rest of the command in the parathesis splits up the line (one line of your textfile) in an array of strings. It uses space as symbol (" ") to split it up into another array of strings. The outer paranthesis are needed for the access identifier at the end of the codeline ([0]), which means, that you only want the first object.

```
}
```

Closes the loop.

Hope this helps

edit: Examplecode:

```
Out-File -FilePath "myergfile.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Force -InputObject "Value"
$lines = Get-Content "C:\ExampleFolder\Example.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines){
  Out-File -FilePath "myergfile.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Append -InputObject ($line.Split(" "))[0]
}
```

Comment: That is super helpful. Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. And then at the end of this part of the code, I can just use export-csv to make it usable in Excel, correct?

Comment: There are two ways to make the array exportable. The easier one is to write the word directly in your file. I will add some lines of code in my answer to explain this further

Comment: Look at the edit-part. Out-File is a cmdlet of powershell to direct some data in a file. Every inputobject will be written in one line of the ergfile. To make a csv you can easily use in excel you need a first line with columnnames. In my example, the columnname is "value". The Fore-Parameter deletes an existing myergfile.csv and create a new one. Use Encoding-Parameter to ensure the use of UTF8. With the "Append"-Parameter you tell out-file not to delete an already existing file.

Comment: This is absolutely great information thank you so much for the help!

Comment: So the loop goes through each line in the txt file, but how do I modify this to loop for every file in the folder as well? Should I add `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ExamplePath -Recurse` and then use `$files` instead of `"C:\ExampleFolder\Example.txt"`

But then how would I name each output file?

Comment: With your $files-Variable you can make another foreach: foreach($file in $files){$lines = Get-Content $file.fullname; foreach ($line in $lines){/*do magic stuff here*/}}. You have a nested foreach in another foreach. You need a way, to get another names für the resulting files or you should create one before the first foreach. Depends on what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content ".\file.txt" | %{ $_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf(" "))} | Select-Object -First 10
```

Remove `|Select-Object -First 10` to get the entire contents of the file.

This solution also assumes that you want to split on the space.

If you add a comma to the end of the output you then you can just save the output as a .csv file that will open in excel.

```
#The default encoding for Out-File [pre v6] is 'Unicode'; in [ps6] it is 'UTF8NoBOM'.  In this example I chose ASCII, though you should choose what best fits your use-case. 
Get-Content ".\file.txt" | %{ $_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf(" ")) + "," } | Out-file -Path ".\output.csv" -Encoding ASCII -Append
```

ref: [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6#parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. For my own learning which part of that is telling it only the first word in each line?

Comment: So we're getting the content of `file.txt`, and for each line `| %{}` we're pulling the substring `$_.Substring()` starting with the first character and ending with the first index of `[space]`......

You can experiment with this on the command line as such... Assign a string variable, `[string]$cheese = "gouda"`, and then `$cheese | Get-Member` to see the methods available such as `IndexOf` and `Substring`. You can also get a cleaner look at exactly what those methods require by calling the method without the brackets. `$cheese.IndexOf`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought that's what it was, but I have no background in code, so I wasn't sure if the " " was for that or if it was something else. Thank you.

Comment: The question doesn't state character encoding for either the input or the output but there shouldn't be an assumption ASCII is right for the output. In fact, some Excel users prefer UTF-8 with BOM (no matter what the range of character is) because Excel uses the BOM as a presumptive signature for the character encoding.

Comment: @TomBlodget Well, you're correct, no one asked, but I chose to specify the option. I will update answer.